# Django select_related returning empty query set if the PK deleted from other table

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

Consider I am having a table that having a foreignkey relation with the user model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
       created_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I am taking queryset like this

```
qs = MyModel.objects.select_related('created_user').all()
```

This query working fine , **but if the user deleted from the database, then it is showing empty queryset**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the instance to be protected after deletion then you can use [`models.PROTECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) option so:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
       created_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

See all the options of [`ForeignKey.on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: Record still there I am facing issue with select_related

Comment: @Anoop Can you please clarify what do you exactly want?

Comment: We are using select related in our queryset for optimizing the query . 

Select related using joining the tables, here the primary key associated with the record not available in the table . So while fetching the query set this record is not showing in the . 

For example 10 records are available but here only showing 9 records .